# Need to read response of 403 Forbidden with WebClient C#

Tags: c#, webclient, httpresponse, http-status-code-403

I am using C# WebClient to get a server response and i get this exception message :

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

this is right page response code is 403 but there is additional  response message i need to read.
this response message is the same i get when i access the server from a web browser.

The first image is showing HTTP headers in chrome.
and the second one shows the response.

what i am asking for is how to get this text/plain response message ?

[image: http headers in chrome]

---

[image: http response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the WebException and read its Response property:

```
try
{
    request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.Response != null)
        return getResponseBody(e.Response);
    else
        throw;
}
```